# how to add a new item in crm 2011 option set by jscript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to add a new option to a Option Set dynamically in page load. Options of Option set are not entered in design time, It will populate only in run time. Is it possible by using Jscript?
eg:
I have a option set named: color.
It have 4 values like: Black, Blue, Red, Green. Now I want to add White as a 5th option to that option set. How can I add White to the Color Option Set by using Java Script?

Answer (score 3):

*edit: this answer comes off a misunderstaing of the requirements. might be helpful to some, but does not solve the issue*

[MSDN entry about Xrm.Page provides the `addOption` method to accomplish this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51828fe3-f6ff-4f97-80ed-b06b3a354955#BKMK_addOption)
This is a **tested, confirmed working** example

```
//Create a new "option" object
var myNewOption = document.createElement("option");
// Option value
myNewOption.value = OPTION_VALUE_HERE;  //example: 4
// Option text
myNewOption.text = 'OPTION_TEXT_HERE';  //example: 'White'
//Add the new option
Xrm.Page.getControl('FIELD_NAME_HERE').addOption(myNewOption); //example: new_color
```

Comment: My Jscript function is like below:: 
var optionsetControl = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_color");
var color="White";
optionsetControl.addOption(color,4);   But it added "Undefined" as the new option to the option set

Comment: @alex-do you have find any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry alex, but I got the Error: "Unable to get the value of the property 'addOption': object is null or undefined".....

Comment: @alex-You can also visit this link posted by me in some another forum, which states something different.....http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/ecc88f20-db46-4d26-92ae-fc5b449c213b

Comment: @alex-noted: I have not added "White" as one option to the "color" field in time of field creation. I need to add "White" typically in Run time, because my program needs this only. The color field of CRM have only 4 values like:Red,Green,Blue & Black.

Comment: @alex-it is working, I have made a mistake to kept the field name under " ", instead of ' '. but the problem is that, the new option WHITE is coming in the option set, but as it is not there in the Option set field previously, when I am clicking on save it not made any effect, not also save to the record db. It is only coming at the page load.

Comment: @aanch Ah I see, I misunderstood. Is customizing the optionset itself not an option I assume ? I'm deleting some of my previous comments to keep em compact.